# How to duplicate a stream that does not support marking

Tags: java, spring-boot

I try to build a HTTP-client with an integrated interceptor (logging in- and outboud).

**Client**

```
...
RestTemplateBuilder rtb = new RestTemplateBuilder ();    
RestTemplate rt = rtb.build ();
HttpHeaders hh = new HttpHeaders ();
HttpEntity <String> he = new HttpEntity <String> ("123", hh);
rt.setInterceptors (Collections.singletonList (new MyInterceptor ()));
ResponseEntity <String> re = rt.exchange ("my.url", HttpMethod.POST, he, String.class);
// I need the body of response here!
System.out.println (re.getBody ());   // null - because body-stream alread read in interceptor
....
```

I need to read the body of the response in the interceptor and also in the client itself.
But that is not working because it is a stream without support of mark.

**Interceptor**

```
public class MyInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor
{
  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept (HttpRequest request, byte [] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException
  {                    
    // ...
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute (request, body);

    String respbody = new String (response.getBody ().readAllBytes ());
    // I need the body here!
    // thats working - but it is empty/null the 2nd time I need it
    return response;
}
```

How to have body in the interceptor AND in the client-code?

Comment: Create a new `ClientHttpResponse` and pass the body again, or wrap it in one that adds the caching functionality.

Comment: How to create that object?

Comment: Please see what I did in this repo https://github.com/smustafa/opa-springboot-demo/tree/main/src/main/java/com/jcompetence/opa/and/inmemory/authentication/security/opa/cachedservlet

Comment: Thanks! In your sample you take care for having the data of the consumed stream later available. But I thought there would be a way to do that by using some standard-mechanics on the stream.

Comment: I forgot but you can wrap your `ClientHttpRequestFactory ` in a `BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory`, which will create a buffering `ClientHttpResponse`. Drawback is that with large responses it can eat up quite some memory.

Comment: I am not the best Java programmer -. so sorry, but I do not see where I can put my ClientHttpResponse in and get a 2nd one back that I can consume/or return.